# cannot detect spotify lens

Tags: 12.04, unity-dash, spotify

today I installed spotify on ubuntu 12.04. The program seems to work quite well for now, so I tried to install spotify-lens. The installation went ok, but the lens doesn't appear in the dash. I tried to use the tool "lenstoggle" (which is my lens manager by now), but spotify-lens didn't appear on the list. So I rebboted the whole system, but it had no effect.

Any idea on how to fix it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Does Spotify has its own lens now, or are you referring to the Spotify scope? When I used it, it was added to the default music scope.

I added it a while back using this guide: http://www.iloveubuntu.net/add-spotify-unity-music-lens-spotify-scope-ubuntu-1110-1204

Not sure of the status now as I've left unity...

Comment: ah, you're right, I got confused. I was referring to spotify scope. I used an identical guide from webupd8.org. I have already installed the scope package, so I should get a "Spotify" entry under the "sources" filter, right? By now, there are only Banshee and Rhythmbox...

Comment: hmm, then I'm not sure what could be the problem. Try purging the packages and installing them again in the correct order. I'm currently on gnome3, but I'll test it later when I'm off work :)

Comment: I have unity instead... Later I'll try to do as you said.